# What is r/o in AppleScript documentation?

Tags: macos, applescript, javascript-automation

In AppleScript documentation, some parameters have `r/o` marked. What is it?

```
name (text, r/o) : Its name.
```

Comment: **R**ead **o**nly?

Comment: Looks like it. Properties with those when set, gives an error. Only the ones without `r/o` is writable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, `r/o` says that the property is read-only, meaning you can retrieve its value, but not set it. Source: Beginning AppleScript. By Stephen G. Kochan, p. 358.

See also AppleScript: The Definitive Guide by Matt Neuburg: Section 20.6.

> A property can be specified as read-only ; this is displayed in Script
>   Editor as "[r/o]", and in Script Debugger as "get" (as opposed to
>   "get/set"). See https://flylib.com/books/en/4.105.1.184/1/